# CodeIgniter - Jamie Rumbelow My Model - Order By Clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have got 2 tables in database City and State. City table has a foreign key state_id.

Database looks like this:

```
City
-----
id    city_name        state_id
--    ---------        -------- 
1     Jersey City      1
2     Philadelphia     2

State
-----
id    state_name    
--    ----------
1     New Jersey
2     Pennsylvania
```

This is how my city model looks like:

```
class City_Model extends MY_Model {
    public $_table = 'city';

    public $belongs_to = array( 'state' );

    public _order_by_state() {
        $this->db->order_by('state_name', 'desc');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch all the cities and the states they belong to order by State name using Jamie Rumbelow's My_Model class. Hence I am trying to achieve this using following piece of code in Controller class:

```
$data['cities'] = $this->city_model->_order_by_state()->with('state')->get_all();
```

The above piece of code gives me following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\application\core\MY_Model.php on line 200
```

This is get_all method in My_Model.php:

```
public function get_all()
{
    $this->trigger('before_get');

    if ($this->soft_delete && $this->_temporary_with_deleted !== TRUE)
    {
        $this->_database->where($this->soft_delete_key, (bool)$this->_temporary_only_deleted);
    }

    $result = $this->_database->get($this->_table)
                       ->{$this->_return_type(1)}(); //Line 200 <- Error Here
    $this->_temporary_return_type = $this->return_type;

    foreach ($result as $key => &$row)
    {
        $row = $this->trigger('after_get', $row, ($key == count($result) - 1));
    }

    $this->_with = array();
    return $result;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could guide me the correct way of using order_by clause here.

Thanks!

Comment: which is line 200 on MY_Model.php, pls...specify

Comment: I have added the get_all method from My_Model.php. Please see Line 200 marked in the code.

Comment: I think Philly's in Pennsylvania

Comment: Yeah I have corrected it.

Comment: have you turned on stack tracing for your errors? i put a debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS) in the erors:error_db.  find it helps immensely.   see http://pastiebin.com/526e55fc41807

Comment: I think you can't order by a column that not belong to City since it's City Model. They are not JOINed with State. so you should find some way to join and then order.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function _order_by_state() {
        $this->db->order_by('state_name', 'desc');
        return $this;
    }
```

and do like this

```
$data['cities'] = $this->city_model->_order_by_state()->get_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  
- Controller  
- There'll be a table called states and i just want to select id (that comes auto) and the state_name, that's why i'm using dropdown()  
*/  

$st = $this->state_model->order_by('state_name')->dropdown('state_name');  
var_dump($st);
```